# strpos() and preg_split() warning

Tags: php, warnings

I have a problem with 2 warnings on one of my page...if you can help me i would really appreciate.

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string
>
> Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string

here is my code:

```
if ( strpos($term, '+') !== false ) {
                $terms = preg_split( '/[+]+/', $term );
                if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $tax_query[] = array_merge( $tax_query_defaults, array(
                        'terms' => array( $term )
                    ) );
                } }
            } else {
                $tax_query[] = array_merge( $tax_query_defaults, array(
                    'terms' => preg_split( '/[,]+/', $term )
                ) );
            }
```

Comment: your `$term` needs to be a string

Comment: a little help, i'm not a pro, how can i do that?

Comment: Use `var_dump($term);` and add what that output is to your question

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (is_string($term) && strlen($term) && strpos($term, '+') !== false ) {
```

on your first line